# What is the difference between Perfect Participle and Perfect Gerund?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, participles

is there the difference between Perfect Participle and Perfect Gerund?

Comment: The perfect gerund typically is of the form “having” + past participle.

Comment: But using perfect participle you also have to use "having + V3 form/ed"

Comment: Did I say something about past particple? I said that using PERFECT PARTICIPLE you have to use   "having + V3 form/ed

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry for the confusion. What kind of difference are you looking for?  They have the same form, but are different parts of speech.

Comment: Am I correctly understand that an indefinite gerund(and perfect gerund) is noun. And participle 1 indefinite (with perfect participle) is adjective?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: @Paul Even perfect forms, yeah?